# How can I find the interval of x? I apply ratio test and get indeterminate. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty({(n+1)(n+2)....(2n)\over n^n})\space (x-2)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty({(n+1)(n+2)....(2n)\over n^n})\space (x-2)^n$$
Find the radius and interval of convergence of the power series given above.

Hi! I am trying to find the interval of x first; however, whenever I apply ratio test, I get indeterminate. How can I find the interval of x?

Here is what I've done:

Convergence:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\cfrac{\lvert(n+2)(n+3)...(2n+2)\space(x-2)^{n+1}\rvert}{\lvert(n+1)^{(n+1)}\rvert}\over\cfrac{\lvert(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)\space(x-2)^n\rvert}{\lvert n^n\rvert}}<1$$
$=>$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\lvert 2(2n+1)(x-2)n^n\rvert}{\lvert(n+1)^{n+1}\rvert}<1$$
$=>$L'Hospital:
$$\lvert x-2\rvert\space\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\lvert (4n+2)\space n^n\rvert}{\vert(n+1)^{n+1}\rvert}<1$$
$=>$
$$\lvert x-2\rvert\space\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\lvert 4n^n+(4n+2).n^n.\ln(n)\rvert}{(n+1)^{n+1}.\ln(n).(\ln1)}$$

As you can see, ln1 makes it indeterminate and I am unable to find.

How can I find the interval of x, so that I can find the interval of convergence and then the radius of convergence?

Comment: You may also try the root test:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}{n^n}(x-2)^n\right|}=|x-2|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n+1}\sqrt[n]{n+2}\cdots\sqrt[n]{2n}}n$$and the remaining limit has the [same value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5BProduct%5B%28n%2Bk%29%5E%281%2Fn%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+n%7D%5D%2Fn%2C+n-%3EInfinity%5D) as provided by the root test (though I'm not exactly sure how one would approach this form of the limit...)

Comment: Yeah, you are right! We learned this way first, so, I just sticked to it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lvert x-2\rvert\space\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\lvert (4n+2)\space n^n\rvert}{\vert(n+1)^{n+1}\rvert}<1\\
\iff|x-2|\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{4n+2}{n}\times\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n\cdot n^{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}<1\\
\iff4|x-2|\times\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^\frac{1}{n+1}<1\\
\iff|x-2|<\dfrac e4$$
Therefore, the required radius of convergence is $\boxed{\dfrac e4}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it!

Comment: @ColleganDelta, You're welcome!

Comment: Hi, again Mr. @Martund ! I just wondered how did you find the interval of x. Because I am unable to get e/4 without interval of convergence. And to find the interval of convergence, I need to find the interval of x.

How did you find it, can you show it step by step? ;-;

Comment: @ColleganDelta, $|x-2|<\dfrac e4\implies -\dfrac e4<x-2<\dfrac e4\implies 2-\dfrac e4<x<2+\dfrac e4$.

Comment: So, you did find the radius of convergence first? We first find the interval of x and thenfind the interval of convergence and THEN the radius of convergene.

How did you manage to find radius, directly?
And one more thing, we check if x less equals or less than any side of the equation at the end. Yes, we have "less than" sign but no matter what, we learned that we should check if it is convergence at the extreme points.

And you haven't checked it, right? If you haven't, why?

Comment: Hi again! I managed to solve! Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$ a_n=\frac{(n+1)...2n}{n^n}$$

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)^2}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$$

using the fact that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}(1+\frac 1n)^n=e$$

we find that

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac 4e$$

The radius of convergence is $$R=\frac e4$$

You can also write $ a_n $ as

$$a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n^n}$$
and use Stirling formula.

Comment: Thank you Mr.; however, Mr. Martund's answer was a little more useful for me. Thanks anyway!